# Monitor.Wait, Pulse - When worker thread should conditionally behave as an actual worker thread

Tags: .net, multithreading

My particular scenario:
- Main thread starts a worker thread.
- Main thread needs to block itself until either worker thread is completed (yeah funny) or worker thread itself informs main thread to go on

Alright, so what I did in main thread:

```
wokerThread.Start(lockObj);
lock(lockObj)
 Monitor.Wait(lockObj);
```

Somewhere in worker thread:

```
if(mainThreadShouldGoOn)
 lock(lockObj)
  Monitor.Pulse(lockObj);
```

Also, at the end of worker thread:

```
lock(lockObj)
 Monitor.Pulse(lockObj);
```

So far, it's working perfect. But is it a good solution? Is there a better one?

EDIT:

What if I do it like this in main thread:

```
Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
workerThread.Start(lockObj);
Monitor.Wait(lockObj);
```

And worker looks like this:

```
void Worker(object lockObj)
{
 Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
 ...
 ...
 ...
 if(mainThreadShouldGoOn)
 {
  Monitor.Pulse(lockObj);
  Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
 }
 ...
 ...
 ...
 if(!mainThreadShouldGoOn)
 {
  Monitor.Pulse(lockObj);
  Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not correct, you run the risk of permanently blocking the main thread if the worker completes too soon.  The proper synchronization object to use here is a ManualResetEvent (or auto, doesn't matter).  Call its Wait() method in the main thread, its Set() method in the worker.  As long as it is a Thread instead of a thread pool thread, using Thread.Join() would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you start a worker thread just to go to sleep right after? You could simply do the work in the main thread!

But assuming you have a reason to do so...

I think your solution is conceptually ok, but there might be a problem. Consider the case when a context switch occurs after the main thread has started the worker but before it would acquire the lock. Then the worker would quickly finish its job within a single time slice. In this case, `Pulse` is called before `Wait`, thus later the main thread will never wake up from the wait. Here's an illustration:

```
class Program
{
    static object theLock = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(WorkerMain);
        worker.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        lock (theLock)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(theLock);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Main done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void WorkerMain()
    {
        lock (theLock)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(theLock);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the time this code will hang. You can fix the problem by moving `worker.Start` inside the scope of the lock.

One more thing to be careful about is making sure that `Pulse` is called, even in exceptional cases. Use try finally's right and you'll be fine.

Or consider separating the task of the worker in two parts: one that is always to be carried out, and the rest that right now follows after the `if(mainThreadShouldGoOn) {...}` check. Then you could execute the first part in a worker thread started by main, and the second part in another worker thread started from the first worker if neccessary. Then you can use `Thread.Join()` to wait for the first worker to be done. This would make synchroniozation simpler and less error prone by sacrificing a little performance.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your detailed reply. Based a bit on your suggestions, I revised my solution. Please see edit in my original post.